# How do i pass a main element to an Actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, menuitem, extends

I am working on a small game, and I want to create an `ItemMenu` ("solve"), but to use it I need to use an element in my main class. For example:

```
public final class FileMenu extends JMenu
{
    public FileMenu(GameFrame gameFrame)
    {
        super("File") ;
        JMenuItem solve = new JMenuItem("Solve");
        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem load = new JMenuItem("Load");
        add(new QuitMenuItem(gameFrame)) ;
        add(solve);
        add(save);
        add(load);
    }
}
```

This is my main class :

```
Maze maze = new Maze(height,width);
MainApplication Application = new MainApplication();
```

I need to create an `ActionListener` for "solve" but to do it I need "Application", how do I use it in `FileMenu`?

Comment: Have you through of passing a reference of `MainApplication` to `FileMenu` (like you do the GameFrame) ?

Comment: What is `MainApplication`?

Comment: MainApplication is a class where i coded a part of my graphic interface, for exemple it's the interface that creates the windows and all the visual parts of my game

Answer (score 0):

It's all about sharing data among classes using [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface#API_in_object-oriented_languages)s:
*In Class FileMenu:*
Store a reference to "solve" JMenuItem.
Create a "getter" API for JMenuItem:  `getJMenuItem(...)`

*In main Class:*
call `getJMenuItem(...).addActionListener(...)`
If you need help understanding how to Use menus you can find it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).

Comment: I am not very familiar with API, can you precise how can i create a getJMenuItem(...) ?